# Dag triggered via TriggerDagRunOperator logs start date greatly different than triggering dag's?

Tags: airflow

Seeing a weird problem where when running a dag on cron schedule

```
0 5 1,3-31 * *
```

(note I am still using UTC time (since I do not believe that I can change it in v1.10.7)) that ends by running a TriggerDagRunOperator task.
When the "triggering" dag runs, the Last Run date shows the correct date and is reflected in the run_id. Eg.

```
2020-03-04 05:00
```

However, the dag that gets triggered shows the Last Run date as 1 day ahead and this unexpected behavior is also reflected in the triggered dag's run_id

```
2020-03-05 05:00
```

yet the triggering dag only takes about 1min. to run.

Does anyone know what could be happening here? 
Is there a time difference that I am not recognizing here (note that I am not living in a UTC time zo

Answer (score 1):

From discussions on the airflow [email list](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/rae4264e1de5bda7cc447883cab7d0e941d70f3759c2cd93e4a4a5d50%40%3Cusers.airflow.apache.org%3E)...

> The execution date of Triggered DAGs has a different logic to
>   Scheduled DAGs (I’m crossing my fingers this inconsistency is resolved
>   in Airflow 2.0 by getting rid of the weird Scheduled DAG logic):
>
> - A Triggered DAG has the execution date of when it is actual run or it’s given time to execute. For example say you set it to run at
>     2020-03-06 12:00:00 then that is it’s execution date.
> - A Scheduled DAG has an execution date that subscribes to the logic that the DAG is processing a “period” of data. So for example if you
>     schedle it to run at midday every day then the run at 2020-03-06
>     12:00:00 considers that period of scheduling to be from 2020-03-05
>     12:00:00 (inclusive) to 2020-03-06 12:00:00 (not inclusive), it then
>     gives you an execution date of 2020-03-05 12:00:00
>
> As you can see even though their actual execution time is the same,
>   their execution date is 1 day apart.
>
> A Triggered DAG can not provide the same logic as a Scheduled DAG
>   because it has no schedule to determine the “period”. I have created
>   Macros that gives me the same execution date regardless of whether I
>   am using Scheduled or Triggered DAGs, you can use the above SO answer
>   as a template if you want to do the same, and the thing to remember is
>   that for a Scheduled DAG the next execution date is equivelent to the
>   Triggered DAG execution date

By default the TriggerDagRunOperator creates a DagRun with execution_date of `utcnow()`, it doesn't inherit the execution_date of the triggering Dag.

Unless you are passing a non default value to TriggerDagRunOperator then you will get the behavior you are seeing.

So in your case the following happened:

- At '2020-03-05 05:00:00' the scheduler created a DagRun for the triggering Dag with an execution_date = '2020-03-04 05:00:00'
- The TriggerDagRunOperator tasks ran creating a DagRun for the triggered Dag with execution_date = nowutc() (which could be very close to '2020-03-05 05:00:00' if the triggering Dag is fast enough.